# Can I assign a value into a moved-from location?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am not sure what the standard says about this situation. I know a moved-from location should be able to destruct, but I do not know if I'm allowed to put a new value into it.

```
std::vector<int> get_user_input(const std::string& prompt) {
  std::vector<int> numbers;
  std::string buffer;

  do {
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
  } while (buffer == "");

  std::stringstream stream (buffer);

  while (std::getline(stream, buffer, ' ')) {
    numbers.push_back(std::atoi(buffer.c_str()));
  }

  return numbers;
}
```

Would the program be incorrect if `std::stringstream stream(std::move(buffer)));` was used instead?

Comment: Not leaving this as an answer since it's tangential to the question, but there's no `std::stringstream` constructor that takes an rvalue-reference to a string, so `buffer` isn't moved from even if you use `std::move` in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the program would not be incorrect. It would behave safely and correctly, since [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move):

> Unless otherwise specified, all standard library objects that **have been moved from are placed in a valid but unspecified state**. That is, only the functions without preconditions, **such as the assignment operator**, can be safely used on the object after it was moved from.

*(emphasis mine)*.

That means your `buffer`, after being moved from, is in correct, but unspecified state - being able to be assigned to something else. Such operation is considered safe in this case. What would *not* be safe, is accessing it via `operator []` and such.

Comment: Would not be safe until you establish the state. `size()` also has no preconditions. You can establish the size and use this to determine if `operator[]` is safe to use.

Comment: How do you know that getline does an assignment to the string and not +=?

Comment: 1. It would be silly, 2. I believe it would still work though

Comment: It wouldn't be silly, that's pretty much how it works. `getline` erases the old string and the extracts one character at a time, until it finds the delimiter (`\n` by default). It still works, though, because `.erase()` has no precondition and puts the string in a specified state (namely empty)

Comment: In this case, my second statement of the comment is correct. I assume we're just nitpicking the implementation details - that's fine, but "it also works since [...]" sounds much better than "what about [...]" followed by "no, it will actually work". I appreciate the input, but imo we should reconsider the form

Answer (score 0):

What can be done to a moved-from object is entirely user-defined (assuming that C++ Standard Library classes are also "user-defined" from the point of view of the core language). So, in general case you need to consult the documentation for the specific class (or library) to determine what can be done with moved-from objects of some specific types.

When it comes to classes from C++ Standard Library the answer is "yes": you can assign to objects of these classes after the have been moved from. Specification of C++ Standard Library explicitly allows that.

A different library might decide to follow a different convention, albeit I'd say that prohibiting such assignment would not make for good design.